# How to run a cmd command from Install4j?

Tags: install4j

I tried the action: `<Run executable or Bath File>` with:

Executable: `${installer:sys.windowsDir}\system32\cmd.exe`
Working directory: `<my directory>`
Arguments: `<tomcat8 //DS//Tomcat8>`
I do set "wait for termination" flag to true, but the command should finish immediately. What happens in fact is that the installer gets stuck.

Comment: "gets stuck" means that the process you started does not return. Temporarily enable the "Show console window" property to see the output.

Comment: The prblem was that I have set the "cmd.exe" as the executable, but it should be the .bat or the .exe file. On the contrary, when running java executable, I had to set the "java.exe" as an executable, and the jar as the parameter. Thank you.